# BigUint shift: cannot infer type

Tags: rust

For the following snippet:

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint; // BigUint;
use num_traits::{ToPrimitive};

fn main() {
    let x = BigUint::parse_bytes(b"123", 10).unwrap();
    let y = x >> 2;
    let z = y.to_u64();

    println!("{:}", y);
}
```

The Rust compiler says:

```
7 |     let z = y.to_u64();
  |             ^ cannot infer type
```

If I annotate the y type to `BigUint`, then, all is fine. Why can't Rust determine that the result of the shift applied to a BigUint is a BigUint? Also, is there any method I could call on (x >> 2) to remove the error (as opposed to creating a new variable and annotating the type) - I'd like to avoid defining new variables just for that.

Comment: Usually this message indicates Rust has several interpretations of what that operation produces, not necessarily just `BigUint`.

Comment: good point. maybe it's because the return value can be both a reference and a non-reference https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint/blob/master/src/biguint/shift.rs#L144-L159

Comment: If you use `x >> 2u32` (or any other integer suffix) the issue is resolved. I think it's because there exist multiple impls for `Shr<{integer}> for BigNum`.

Comment: Using `x >> 2i32` can bypass the error, but I'm not completely sure why... if the `2` was ambiguous, why would the compiler complain about `y` instead?

Comment: @kmdreko Having ambiguous `y` is fine until you actually use it, in which case it needs to be nailed down. If the usage doesn't hint at the type, you get an error. Here `to_u64()` doesn't impose any particular constraints.

Comment: @tadman If `y` were truly ambiguous, then the `println!` would complain as well, but it doesn't. It seems to work under the assumption that `2` was `i32` until that assumption is questioned by a method lookup and it backtracks saying "woops I'm not actually sure what y is". Very unintuitive: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=624d9d78ac6c0d9b69c94397b279ab86

Comment: This is very strange. I would have expected for sure that this would work. But yes, I agree that it must have something to do with the strange behaviour of integer constants, which default to `i32` under some circumstances but can then be derived in other circumstances. Very strange.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman always has this kind of deep knowledge, maybe he knows?

Comment: My gut feeling says that it's because there are many `Shr` implementations. They do all produce a `BigNum`, but I don't think the compiler is smart enough to derive an output type from "all implementations produce the same type". So as long as nothing more specific is asked it assumes `i32` as the shift parameter and uses that type. But as soon as a function is called on it, it tries to figure out the exact type and backpropagates the request to find the specific type, and then realizes that the shift parameter doesn't have a strong type. And fails to get a definite type.

Comment: Although as @kmdreko already pointed out, the fact that `println!` compiles really kind of negates that theory ... I'd be really interested in what happens under the hood here.